# Sort ArrayList data

Tags: java, database, sorting

I'm preparing for an exam. I can read the CSV file but I don't know how to sort a data line.

For example, if "SchoolName.csv" has

```
Cayuga,Elkhart,Slocum,Westwood                                            
Neches,Palestine,central
Dibolon
Lufkin,Holiday
```

After I sort the data the output should be

```
Dibolon // becuase it only contain one name.
Lufkin,Holiday
Neches,Palestine,central
Cayuga,Elkhart,Slocum,Westwood
```

Comment: You want to sort by the number of names on a row?

Comment: yes;i want to sort by how many names they conatin @GuiSim

Answer (score 2):

So you want to sort based on number of elements. Assuming you have those elements in a `Collection<String> csvlines`:

```
csvlines.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(line -> StringUtils.countMatches(line, ",")))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: I would suggest using `Comparator.comparing(line -> StringUtils.countMatches(line, ","))` in your `sorted()`

Comment: You're right! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort each row based on the number of names, you could do it like this

```
// Read the file's lines
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(pathToFile);

List<String> sortedLines = lines.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(line -> line.split(",").length)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Files.lines(...)` can be used instead of `Files.readAllLines(...).stream()`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a comparator, That is a class extending comparator and pass it as an argument to `arraylistname.sort(comparator);`

A comparator returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer if the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

so

```
class CompareByLength implements Comparator {
   compare(list a, list b) {
      return a.size()-b.size();
   }
}
```

alternatively use `b.size()-a.size()` if you want your list ordered the other way round.